Is it possible to access data from your phone from the boot menu? (Motorola One Hyper)
Firstly, I have found a similar question here (Is there a way to access my phone data from the boot menu or to fix an android OS without factory reset? Or even to stop the restart from happening?), but no answer there seemed to solve the behavior.
I am experiencing the same sort of problem that seems to be affecting multiple Motorola One Hyper in my country and abroad. The phone boots, stays on for about 10 seconds, then automatically restarts, prompting a factory reset, which I do not want do do, given that there are many personal files still inside the phone.
During this brief period of time, I can see my files there, which is why I'm asking this question. I don't really care about the phone anymore, it had its day already and I am willing to break it down entirely if needed, the only thing I want to do is to have one clean boot or method to access my files and transfer them to another storage.
Any tips on what I could try, or where I could start to make things work? Thank you very much in advance.

What is the exact message you get when the phone asks for a factory reset? In the 10 seconds when it is on can you normally use it? Does the reboot after 10 sec also occurs when a charger is connected (such a reboot is often an indicator of a next to dead battery)?

Hi, @Robert.  The reboots started after the battery suddenly went to zero and, upon connecting the charger, skyrocketed to 49% out of nothing, so, on the first time a charger was connected. However, it was not the phone's charger, but a spare one I have. The message it shows is "Restoring to factory reset"  - which it does not do, simply returning to the boot screen. Also, during the ten seconds I can access some apps, like Google Photos, but not all of them as the phone is still booting up. I have had times on which it stayed on for minutes, but when I navigate the phone it reboots.

First enable Air Plane mode and make sure Wifi is disabled. If the phone is offline this may reduce the chance of a sudden crash. Second use the time and enable Developer options + ADB. With adb you have the best chance to extract at least some of data stored on the phone. Also install minimal adb and the necessary drivers on the connected PC.
